# How to execute multiple scripts when openvpn establishes?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I am using *ubuntu 12.04* to connect to an openvpn server.

Two scripts, *update-resolv-conf* and *vpn-up.sh*, in /etc/openvpn should be executed when the connection established.

The following commands are added to the configure file *client.ovpn* to make the two scripts run when openvpn connects and stop when openvpn disconnects:

```
script-security 2
up /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
up /etc/openvpn/vpn-up.sh
down /etc/openvpn/vpn-down.sh
down /etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf
```

However, during connection only the first script is executed. And every time I have to run the script *vpn-up.sh* individually by hand. So I want to know how to get them both work when openvpn tunnel is established?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick hack would be to call the 2nd script from the end of the last one:

Just add the following to the end of the '/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf' script:

> `/etc/openvpn/vpn-up.sh`

I'm sure people here will provide a more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 11):

Just for reference. If you have a few scripts and timing isn't crucial you can also use another parameter for executing scripts.

```
Script Order of Execution

--up
Executed after TCP/UDP socket bind and TUN/TAP open.
--tls-verify
Executed when we have a still untrusted remote peer.
--ipchange
Executed after connection authentication, or remote IP address change.
--client-connect
Executed in --mode server mode immediately after client authentication.
--route-up
Executed after connection authentication, either immediately after, or some number of seconds after as defined by the --route-delay option.
--client-disconnect
Executed in --mode server mode on client instance shutdown.
--down
Executed after TCP/UDP and TUN/TAP close.
--learn-address
Executed in --mode server mode whenever an IPv4 address/route or MAC address is added to OpenVPN's internal routing table.
--auth-user-pass-verify
Executed in --mode server mode on new client connections, when the client is still untrusted.
```

https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html

Answer (score 3):

```
up '/bin/bash -c "/etc/openvpn/update-resolv-conf; /etc/openvpn/vpn-up.sh"'
```